# ThingsBoard PE :Parse incoming MQTT/JSON string

Tags: json, thingsboard

I've been struggling now for days to understand the way TB maps incoming data.

I have an incoming MQTT stream which gets received into TB as a keypair of

Data:{"Temperature":"21.800000000000001","Humidity":"51.5"}

No matter what I try, I can't access the individual keypairs in the 'Data' packet.  I just want to draw graphs in the dashboard of each parameter and it shouldn't be that hard.

I'm trying to demo this to a client tomorrow and I clearly can't see the light of how TB models this data can anyone help me, please?

EDIT: I should make it clear that I can see the WHOLE data:payload packet as incoming telemetry in TB, but I can't seem to map the actual data to an 'entity alias' so that I can graph it.

Comment: Thingsboard PE? I think you already paid for official support. use it :) However, how do you send your data to TB? What do the mqtt messages look like? I think TB expects rather `{"temp:" 123, "hum": 321}` instead of `{"Data": {"temp:" 123, "hum": 321}}` (it's just a wild guess)

Comment: Thanks for the reply lupz, No, ThingsBoard PE has a trial version also.  Only using that because it didn't let me open a second account on CE.  Yes, you are right that I have a JSON String within a JSON string, but AFAIK this is still perfectly valid JSON, so TB should be able to deal with this, it's not like its a totally unusual situation.

Comment: In fact Thingsboard is able to deal with your json as it already saves your telemetry for the device :) The point is this: Thingsboard will save the values of all the keys it finds directly in the telemetry message. When you send `{"temp": value1, "hum": value2}` it will save the two values for their keys. When you send `{"data": { ... perfectly valid json ... }}` it will save one value and interpreting the json is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of telemetry API is the same for CE and PE versions. Most likely, you are pushing

```
{"Data":{"Temperature":"21.800000000000001","Humidity":"51.5"}}
```

In such a case, you are inserting one telemetry key called "Data" with a value "{"Temperature":"21.800000000000001","Humidity":"51.5"}". In this case, value is of type JSON and not a primitive. So, you can't (easily) use it for graphing. Only for processing in the rule engine. I would recommend to send simply {"Temperature":"21.800000000000001","Humidity":"51.5"} (without "Data", no nested JSON).

If you can't do this due to limitations of device/firmware/etc, you can convert the incoming data in the Rule Engine and extract Temperature and Humidity. This is done using Transformation rule node which is basically a user-defined JS function. See Docs->Guides->Transform Incoming Telemetry for an example.